# Why do I need to add the 'run' argument when building an angular app (npm run build)?

Tags: angular-cli, npm-scripts

I'm just being curious. This is a portion of the package.json file

```
"start": "ng serve -o",
"build": "ng build",
"build-prod": "ng build --prod",
"test": "ng test",
```

I'm just curious. Why does writing `npm start` and `npm test` work. However, npm build or npm build-prod gives me the following error `build` npm build `called with no arguments. Did you mean to 'npm run-script build'?` Why do I need to add **run** when building? `npm run build` or `npm run build-prod`

Thanks for helping

Comment: someone voted down the question. Is there any reason? Is that obvious why some times I should use `run` and another time I should skip `run`? Please let me know or point me to a link. I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *"Description"* section of the [npm-run](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script#description) documentation it states:

> *"`run[-script]` is used by the **test**, **start**, **restart**, and **stop** commands, **but can be called directly, as well.**"*

<sub>**Note:** Bold emphasis added by me</sub>

Essentially, npm considers any script defined in the `scripts` section of *package.json* that is named; `test`, `start`, `restart`, or `stop`, to be a *"lifecycle"* script. Any one of those four *"lifecycle"* scripts can be invoked *without* the `run` keyword.

Each of the aforementioned four npm script names, (i.e. *"lifecycle"* scripts) , have a decicated [ClI Command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands), namely [`npm test`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-test), [`npm start`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-start), [`npm restart`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-restart), and [`npm stop`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-stop), for invoking them.

As an example consider the following contrived `"scripts"` section defined in *package.json*:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "echo \"starting...\"",
  "restart": "echo \"restarting...\"",
  "stop": "echo \"stopping...\"",
  "test": "echo \"testing...\"",

  "foo": "echo \"foo...\""
},
```

- The script named `foo` is the only script that must be invoked using the `run` keyword, i.e. `npm run foo`.
- Unlike the others, namely: `start`, `restart`, `stop`, and `test`, they can be invoked without the `run` keyword; i.e. `npm start`, `npm stop` and so on.

  <sub>**Side Note:** `start`, `restart`, `stop`, and `test` can be invoked with the `run` keyword too. i.e. `npm run start`, `npm run stop` and so on.</sub>

The docs also state the following about `npm run`:

> *"If no "command" is provided, it will list the available scripts [...] When the scripts in the package are printed out, they're separated into lifecycle (test, start, restart) and directly-run scripts."*

So given the *package.json* shown in your question, if you `cd` to your project directory and run `npm run` you'll see that both the `start` and `test` scripts are listed under the *"Lifecycle"* section.